# Spring-Boot and sdkman

Tags: spring-boot, sdkman

I develop Java-applications for many years now and in my latest projects I've used Spring-Boot with great success. On the other hand I like to work with sdkman. It is a tool which saves me a lot of time when I set up my infrastructure by preparing maven, gradle, groovy, ...,  (I hope even JDK's in future) but I cannot find a use case to manage Spring-Boot with sdkman. When I start a project I manage my dependencies with Gradle/Maven - and Spring-Boot is just a dependency. So what is the benefit of installing Spring-Boot via sdkman?

Answer (score 2):

You're describing one of the uses of Spring Boot (a mere dependency in your project). However Spring Boot also offers you a [CLI](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-installing-the-cli) for tasks like running a server or executing tests.

You could say that sdkman is aimed for libraries that expose interfaces through Unix shells.